# GPG using sudo under another user, is `pinentry-mode loopback` safe?

Tags: sudo, gpg, pinentry

There are 2 users: user1 and user2. When trying to use gpg via sudo *(symmetric decryption)*:

`user1@host: sudo -u user2 gpg /home/user2/pass.gpg`

an error
`gpg: decryption failed: No secret key`.

I set it to `--pinentry-mode loopback` and the password request happens (right in the terminal), I type and the decryption happens. Tell me, is this approach safe?

I can't understand how this option works. The GnuPG website says:

> Redirect Pinentry queries to the caller. This enables the use of
> gpgme_set_passphrase_cb because pinentry queries are redirected to
> gpgme.